# Sails.js object has undefined collection after populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Whenever I populate a collection in Sails.js, the values are populated inside `modelName.associations.collectionName.value`. The value of `modelName.collectionName` is always undefined even though when I represent the object as  JSON everything is shown perfectly.

Taking the example of a Many-to-Many relationship given in the documentation (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html), if I do the following query:

```
User.findOne(1)
.populate('pets')
.exec(function(err, owner) {...});
```

I would get the pets collection in `owner.associations.pets.value`, but `owner.pets` is undefined.

Any ideas what is going on here?

**EDIT:**

I have replicated the exact same example given in the documentation (the same `Pet.js`, `User.js` and `bootstrap.js`) and I have overridden the `findOne` blueprint of `User.js` in this way:

```
findOne: function (req, res) {

  User.findOne(req.params.id)
    .populate('pets')
    .exec(function(err, owner) {
      if (err) return res.send(err, 500);
      return res.json(owner);
    });

}
```

As I expected, the JSON response is alright, but if I set a breakpoint inside the `exec(..)` function, `owner.pets` is undefined. The data is only in `owner.associations.pets.value`.

Could it be my version of Sails.js? It's 0.10.0-rc11.

Comment: `model.associations.pets.value` is essentially a private API, and not something you should be relying on at all.  It's hard to say what your issue is without seeing your actual model and query code, but if your example really looks like the one above, the first problem I can see is that you're not sending any criteria to the `findOne` call--it needs at least a primary key, or else an object with the query critera, e.g. {name: 'dan'}.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that... edited. I will try to replicate the same example as in the documentation and see if I get the same thing.